# Referring to the Seasons correctly: Summer versus Summers

Tags: word-usage

Which of the below seems the correct usage:

(A) The family spent the academic year in Berkeley, retreating to a Napa Valley estate *in the summers.*

(B) The family spent the academic year in Berkeley, retreating to a Napa Valley estate *in the summer.*

(C) The family spent the academic year in Berkeley, retreating to a Napa Valley estate *in summer.*

Context: This is not something they did just one year, but seems a habitual, year after year trip.

Follow up question: Is "in the winters" also used? I somehow hear of it less often than "in winter".

More Context: The original sentence was taken  from Wikipedia and conforms to Usage (A) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursula_K._Le_Guin

Since (A) is on Wikipedia I tend to go with that but in reality none of the three sound odd to my ears.

Comment: They are all correct, since *summer* can be either a mass or a count noun.

Comment: Hi curious_cat (love the username, btw). Please tell us which one you suspect to be right/wrong and why. Include your research, and maybe some links pointing to it. Otherwise, this runs the risk of getting closed.

Comment: @TusharRaj: The other question does not have any reference to the plural form at all. It is the plural form that I see used in the original article (link added)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Maybe. I quoted (A) verbatim from its source.

Comment: Thanks @PeterShor. PS. Are you really THE Peter Shor? I'm dazzled.  :)

Answer (score 1):

All are grammatical. There are two separate questions here:

Summer or summers? Either is fine and in your example there would be no difference in meaning.

Is "the" required? It's optional. Most speakers wouldn't use it here.

Comment: -1 because in no way, shape or form do Anglophones honour a general principle whereby a usage is "preferable because it omits a needless word".

Comment: As it happens, I watched 1984 last night - half a century after reading the book! Orwell gets a bit carried away in that essay, but obviously his 1984 Newspeak isn't meant to serve as a model for "quality writing". From the subtitle file: *Plusbig **waste is in adjectives**. Plusbig problem is timing the language to scientific advance. **It's a beautiful thing, the destruction of words**.* Yeah yeah. But noting your edit, downvote cancelled (I admit it, partly I just didn't like "commoner").

Comment: Your answer and comments are way too wordy. You're not following your own rules. Which don't have anything to do with English in the first place. Advocates of brevity advocate brevity, and not brevity in one language but not others. Oh, and Strunk and White can't tell a word from a hole in the ground, and they constantly break their own rules even in the very wording of said rules. They are not considered an authority of any kind here.

Comment: @RegDwight I agree with what you say about Strunk and White. I'm not using them as an authority. I'm using them as counterexamples to the claim that no English speakers followed such a rule, a rule which I note in passing, you too seem to be advocating.

In my answer I have taken into account what's grammatical and what sounds best and explained why I felt that way. That's how I would want such a question answered if I were asking it.